# Real polynomials, complex zeroes and the Intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I have a second grad polynomial p(x). For arguments sake lets say

$$p(x) = x^2 + 16x + 76$$

I also have an inequation

$$p(x) > 0$$

Now the inequation does not have a real solution, but only complex ones.
Which means, if you plotted it, that the graph of the function does not intersect with the $x$-axis.

So for $p(x) > 0$, all the real numbers are the solution. For $p(x) < 0$ we would have no solution.

Now I am supposed to connect this all to the Intermediate Value Theorem and I simply dont understand how.

How can I use the IVT to show for a $p(x) > 0$ (or $p(x) < 0$), that all the real numbers are the solution (or what the solution is in general, if you didnt know that in such a case all real numbers are a solution)?

EDIT: by no real solutions i mean when I dont get real solutions when doing

$$-\frac p2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{p^2}4 -q}$$

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing. Are you trying to say that you want to prove that for every quadratic polynomial, either $p(x)>0$ or $p(x)<0$ is true for all real numbers? If so, you are wrong, since $x^2-1$ clearly has values both smaller and larger than $0$.

Comment: Yea not native english. makes it harder.
I was told to use the intermediate value theorem to show that it is not necessarily a problem when an inequation p(x) > 0 does only have a complex solution. That you can somehow use the IVT to still come up with the solution of the inequation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are saying now. When a second order equation $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c = 0$ does not have any real solutions, that means that for every $x\in\mathbb R$, you know that $p(x)\neq 0$. Now, let us say for the sake of argument that you know that $p(0)>0$. If there exists a value $x_0$ such that $p(x_0)<0$, then, by IVT, you know that $p$ has some root, but that is not true. This means that $p(x)>0$ for all values of $x$.

The same argument can be made if $p(0)<0$ (reversing all the signs).

Comment: Im not sure Im allowed to assume this. Maybe I should have added that all this is the result from solving an inequation of the form f(x) < g(x)/h(x). To solve that I obviously have to consider whether h(x) is negative or positive, which makes me end up with two inequations p(x) > 0 and p(x) < 0. Now I guess your argument is still valid, because after all I know the signs and can therefore assume that p(x) > 0 is always true.

Comment: I am not assuming anything else than the fact that $p(x)=0$ has no real solutions. Then, I split my argument. If $p(0)>0$, then $p(x)>0$ for all values of $x$. If $p(0)<0$, then $p(x)<0$ for all values of $x$. In both cases, you have that either $\forall x: p(x)>0$ or $\forall x: p(x)<0$ holds.

Comment: Aah I think I understood. Because I know that p(0) > 0 is true in my example I can go ahead and assume that no x_0 exists such that p(x_0) < 0, because of the IVT. tyvm!

Comment: That is correct. In general, if you do not know any of the values of $p$, but you know that it has no roots, you can only say that either all the values are negative or all of them are positive. PS: if you recieved the answer you wanted, consider voting on it and accepting it as this is standard practice on this site.

Comment: Ofc, I was going to do that in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Well, by examining the polynomial derivative ($p'(x) = 2x+16$) we find where $p(x)$ assumes its minimum value ($p'(x) = 2x+16=0$; by solving $2x+16 > 0$ we get $x=-8$ is a minimum). Now, $p(-8) =64-16\cdot 8+76=12$. Instead $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} p(x) = +\infty$, so by the $IVT$, the polynomial assumes all the values from $12$ to $+\infty$...

Comment: Shouldnt the polynomial assume all values tho, not just from 12 to +infinity?

Comment: Not exactly...the minimum  is $(-8;+12)$, then no real number $<12$ can be reached by the polynomial

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding and I hope i dont annoy you, but: When I enter the inequation into WolframAlpha, then it tells me that xϵR is the solution.

Comment: Of course! You entered the derivative inequality: $x\in \Bbb{R}$ means that the polynomial is derivable $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$...$p'(x) >0 \\ 2x+16 > 0 \\ x > -8$ means that $\forall x>-8 p(x)$ is increasing and $\forall x>-8 p(x)$ is decreasing, reaching its minimum just when $x=-8$. I hope to have shown things crystal clear now ;)

Comment: No wait, Ive entered my original p(x), not the derivative. Told it to solve the inequation and it shows me the result is all real numbers and also shows me the plot where you can see that all real numbers are valid for x.

Comment: And it's completely right! Because $p(x) = x^2+16x+76$ has its minimum in $(-8;+12)\to$ it's positive $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$!

Comment: aaah ok now I understand where you were coming from. Sorry it took so long.